# Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)

Tags: c++

I need to work on a project that was written in msvcpp6.0sp6

**I DIDN'T write the project. I know very little about its inner works. I DO know it WAS POSSIBLE to build it in the past.**

while trying to build this project that was built successfuly in the past(not by me)

I get the error:

```
        Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast (static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)
```

for example:
    error C2664: 'strncpy' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const unsigned short *' to 'const char *'

error C2664: 'void __cdecl CString::Format(const unsigned short *,...)' : cannot convert parameter 1

for a few dozen implicit conversions. I mustn't change the code. how can I force the complier to accept the implicit convertions?

Comment: The first error you posted has nothing to do with the second error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mustn't change the code. how can I force the complier to accept the
>   implicit convertions?

Quite likely you need to get the same compiler that was used for the code in the first place, and use that.

If my guess (in a comment on unwind's answer) is correct about that `unsigned short*` error then it's simply not possible to compile this code in Unicode mode, because the source is insufficiently portable. Suppressing the error for the conversion, even if it's possible via some compiler setting, will just result in code that compiles but doesn't work.

I'd expect that also to imply that the old dll probably isn't compatible with the rest of your current code, but if you've been using it up to now then either I'm wrong about the reason, or else you've got away with it somehow.

Comment: thank you! moved to asci mode and it solved the problem.the thank you is for actually trying to solve the problem as I need and not as you wish,

Answer (score 1):

That sounds crazy.

The use of `unsigned short *` with string-handling functions like `strncpy()` initially seems to make no sense at all. On second thought though, it makes me wonder if there is some kind of "wide character" configuration that is failing. If `strncpy()` was "re-targeted" by the compiler to work on 16-bit characters, having it expect `unsigned short *` makes sense and would explain why the code passes it such. At least "kind of" explain, it's still odd.

Comment: I suspect that error is because the original code was written for an ASCII build, where `TCHAR` was char, and it passed `TCHAR*` to `strncpy`. The questioner is now trying to build the same source for Unicode, `TCHAR` is `unsigned short`, trouble. So it's not `strncpy` that's changed, it's the type used by the calling code.

Comment: @SteveJessop thats entierly possible. as I mentioned it is a very old project. how can I force it to build as it was?

Comment: @Nahum: well, you could try compiling it in ASCII mode (or narrow-character mode, I can't remember what MSVC calls it). That won't do anything about the enum conversion, but it's progress of a sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There are no such implicit conversions defined by the C++ language.

Visual C++ 6.0 was a law unto itself; by implementing something that merely looked a bit like the C++ language, it may have accepted this invalid code.

Comment: VC6 was indeed like that, although at the time STL was still fairly new and at least it had it and supported templates possibly as well as any compiler did at its time when most compilers couldn't handle them very well.

VC6 was the compiler when C++ as a language was at its most popular, probably because of the project-generating wizards and all the sample code you got with it that allowed you to "get going" on your project.

It may have been more backwardly-compatible with C than later compilers thus allowing certain actions without casting.

Comment: @CashCow: More to the point, it was released in the same year as the first C++ Standard. Think how many bugs and incomplete features there were in C++11 in GCC releases last year.

Comment: Also as a commercial compiler vendor, Microsoft would have had to consider that breaking existing customer's non-compliant legacy code would have inhibited adoption of the new compiler.  So it was probably intentionally permissive.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a typesafe language. But it allows you to tell the compiler to "shut up" by the evil known as casting.

Casting from integers to enums is often a necessary "evil" cast, for example, you cannot loop through enums where you have, say, a restricted number of values for which you have given enumerations. Therefore you have to use an integer and cast them to enums for this purpose.

Sometimes you do need to cast data structors to const char * rather than const void * just so you can perform pointer arithmetic. However for the purpose of strcpy, it is difficult to see why you want to cast in unsigned shorts. If these are wide characters (and the old compiler did not know of wchar_t) then it may be "safe" to cast it to const wchar_t * and use it in a wide-string copy. You could also use C++ strings, i.e. std::string and std::wstring.

Comment: This isn not my code. this is a very very very old code of a dll that I must add a function to. I don't want to touch anything that already workes.

Comment: @Nahum: "fails to compile using our current toolchain" is a funny definition of "already works" ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop yes but how to can guess the original chain? changing the code is TOTALLY out of the question.

Comment: @Nahum: your situation is absurd. You have a blob of binary data (a dll), you have no idea how it was produced. You're not allowed to change it, except that you're required to change it (to add another function to the source and recompile). I'm not going to help some manager hand down stupid, contradictory restrictions onto you even if I could. But I'm pretty sure that it's not possible to recover from a dll the precise compiler version and options it was built with.

Comment: ... I suppose you could install MSVC 6 and tweak the project settings in the hope of producing a binary-identical dll, which tells you that what you've found is "close enough" to the original settings. But that could take weeks and still fail, the time might be better spent hunting down whoever checked in the binary file in the first place without providing the means to reproduce it, and torturing them. Or more realistically, reverse engineer the data structures used by the dll and implement the new function from scratch, without touching the old dll.

Comment: @Nahum.  You are already changing the code is you are adding a function to it! Just using a different compiler will change the binary code if not the source. Moreover adding a explicit cast where an implicit one was will have no affect on the binary produced (excepting the different code generation that a different compiler will inevitably apply in any case).

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not wish to update the source code for ISO compliance then your best bet is to use the original VC++ 6.0 compiler for your legacy code.  Not least because even though you know this code to work, if it were compiled with a different compiler it will be *different code* and may no longer work.  Any undefined or implementation defined compiler behaviour either exploited or used inadvertently could cause problems if a different compiler is used.

If you have an MSDN subscription, you can download all previous versions of VC++ for this purpose.